# Variable mysteriously being changed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So, this is something of a followup to my previous question. I'm running into an odd bug, and can't figure out whats wrong. Essentially, I wrote the following code to detect when text was entered in a text box, and change the variables accordingly:

```
-(void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSTextView *fieldEditor = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor"];

    if ([[aNotification object] isEqualTo:[self idField]])
    {

        [self setIdNumber:[[fieldEditor textStorage] string]];
    }
    else if ([[aNotification object] isEqualTo:[self chapterField]])
    {

        [self setChapterNumber:[[fieldEditor textStorage] string]];

    }

}
```

This takes the entered text, checks which text box is being edited, and changes a variable depending on which box is edited. The problem is that "else if.." block of code changes both the variables chapterNumber and IdNumber to the entered text, even though there is only code for changing chapterNumber. I just can't figure out whats wrong...

Comment: Check your IBOutlet connections? There's nothing wrong with this as shown. Where and how are you examining the values of those two variables?

Comment: The IBOutlets seem to be connected correctly. I checked the values of the variables by using an NSLog statement immediately before and after they get set, which is how I isolated the change to this part of the code.

Comment: So, I seem to have figured out the problem, although I'm not sure why this works this way. Essentially, I changed the set statements to use NSString's method StringWithString...

Comment: Okay, I know what's wrong then. This has bitten me before. I was confused by the fact that you _only_ said that the `else if` block changes both `IDNumber` and `chapterNumber`. Actually, though, either block of the `if` would change both values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were experiencing this problem because your two setter methods `setIdNumber:` and `setChapterNumber:` aren't copying the string that's in the field editor, but just pointing at it.

The field editor, as you may know, is an `NSTextView` which is reused by whichever text field happens to have focus at the moment. It's always the same object, and that object's `string` is changed depending on what text field it's attached to.

When you assign a variable to the field editor's `string`, you are assigning a *pointer*; whatever variable you're assigning now has the *address* of that string. Since the field editor is always the same object, the address of the string stays the same even if the contents change, and so any pointer that you have -- any variable to which you've assigned that string -- will appear to change its value.

If you make a *new* string using the *contents* of the field editor's string, using `copy` or `stringWithString:` or some other means, then you get a new object, at an address that the field editor can't change, and each variable to which you have assigned such a copy will continue to yield the value in the copied string no matter what happens to the field editor.